# Is calling tex3D on a 2d texture legal?

Tags: directx-9

In Direct3D9, if I use tex3D in a HLSL program, on a sampler with a 2D texture bound what happens?  Is this a legal operation, or is it undefined?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it, it just seems to work on my nvidia card, but I cannot find anything on if this is defined behavior.

Logically I would argue that you are doing a lookup on a x*y*1 texture, so even activated interpolation would always result in a lookup to the only 3d-plane available.